# subprocess.check_call: Command '['git', 'clone']' returned non-zero exit status 127

Tags: python, git, ssh, subprocess, clone

I am working on a microservice for which have written the following script for a user, which wants to `ssh` into an remote environment and `git clone` a repo. I have specified the `GIT_SSH` and `GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE` for the environment and then run `git clone`.

```
def clone_if_local_repo_absent(local_repo_path, remote_repo_url):
    GIT_SSH = '...'
    GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE = '/usr/bin/git'
    my_env = os.environ.copy()
    my_env["GIT_SSH"] = GIT_SSH
    my_env["GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE"] = GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE
    # Clones to directory specified
    exe_command = shlex.split('git clone {remote_repo_url} {repo_name}'.format(remote_repo_url=remote_repo_url, repo_name=local_repo_path))
    subprocess.check_call(exe_command, env=my_env, shell=True)
```

On running the script, I get the error: `Command '['git', 'clone', remote_repo_url, 'LOCAL']' returned non-zero exit status 127.`
How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why don't you use something like [gitpython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: Why `str.format` and `shlex.split` instead of simply `check_call(['git', 'clone', remote_repo_url, local_repo_path], ...)`?

Comment: And about the error - that means git failed. Did you try `git clone remote_repo_url LOCAL` from the console and see what git complains about?

Comment: I can't use gitpython since it is not installed in the remote environment. Git is also not installed in the remote environment. So I am trying to pass the GIT_SSH into the `git clone` command in the `subprocess call`. However, `git clone` still cannot be executed since it shows the exit status 127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Git ProBook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_miscellaneous):

> `GIT_SSH`, if specified, is a program that is invoked instead of `ssh` when Git tries to connect to an SSH host.
> It is invoked like `$GIT_SSH [username@]host [-p <port>] <command>`.
>
> Note that this isn’t the easiest way to customize how ssh is invoked; it won’t support extra command-line parameters, so you’d have to write a wrapper script and set GIT_SSH to point to it.
> It’s probably easier just to use the `~/.ssh/config` file for that.

SO this is not executed on the remote side at all. It is executed to connect to the remote server.

If Git is not installed on the remote environment, any `git clone` executed from the ssh session would not work.